# Runtime Error (Python3) when you manipulate lists with very long strings

Tags: python, string, list, runtime-error

I wrote a Python3 code to manipulate lists of strings but the code gives Runtime Error for long strings. Here is my code for the problem:

```
string = "BANANA"
slist= list (string)
mark = list(range(len(slist)))
vowel_substrings = list()
consonants_substrings = list()
#print(mark)
for i in range(len(slist)):
    if slist[i]=='A' or slist[i]=='E' or slist[i]=='I' or slist[i]=='O' or mark[i]=='U':
        mark[i] = 1
    else:
        mark[i] = 0
#print(mark)

for j in range(len(slist)):
    if mark[j] == 1:
        for l in range(j,len(string)):
            vowel_substrings.append(string[j:l+1])
            #print(string[j:l+1])
    else:
        for l in range(j,len(string)):
            consonants_substrings.append(string[j:l+1])
            
#print(consonants_substrings)     
unique_consonants = list(set(consonants_substrings))
unique_vowels = list(set(vowel_substrings))
##add two lists
all_substrings = consonants_substrings+(vowel_substrings)
#print(all_substrings)     

##Find points earned by vowel guy and consonant guy
vowel_guy_score = 0
consonant_guy_score = 0

for strng in unique_vowels:
    vowel_guy_score += vowel_substrings.count(strng)
    
for strng in unique_consonants:
    consonant_guy_score += consonants_substrings.count(strng)
#print(vowel_guy_score) #Kevin
#print(consonant_guy_score) #Stuart

if vowel_guy_score > consonant_guy_score:
    print("Kevin ",vowel_guy_score)
elif vowel_guy_score < consonant_guy_score:
    print("Stuart ",consonant_guy_score)    
else:
    print("Draw")
```

gives the right answer. But if you have a long string, shown below, it fails.
`NANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANAN`
I think initialization or memory allocation might be a problem but I don't know how to allocate memory before even knowing how much memory the code will need. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just a note that `for j, val in enumerate(slist):` is probably better than `for j in range(len(slist)):` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522578/1270789) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle there, you generate a data structure of size O(n³): for each starting position × each ending position × length of the substring. That's probably where your memory problems appear (you haven't posted a traceback).

One possible optimisation would be, instead of having a list of substrings and then generating the set, use instead a [`Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). That would let you know how many times each substring appears without storing all the copies:

```
vowel_substrings = collections.Counter()
consonant_substrings = collections.Counter()

for j in range(len(slist)):
    if mark[j] == 1:
        for l in range(j,len(string)):
            vowel_substrings[string[j:l+1]] += 1
            #print(string[j:l+1])
    else:
        for l in range(j,len(string)):
            consonants_substrings[string[j:l+1]] += 1
```

Even better would be to calculate the scores as you go along, without storing any of the substrings. If I'm reading the code correctly, the substrings aren't actually used for anything — each letter is effectively scored based on its distance from the end of the string, and the scores are added up. This can be calculated in a single pass through the string, without making any additional copies or keeping track of anything other than the cumulative scores and the length of the string.

Comment: That solves the problem for that text, I think, but for strings with few common substrings you'll still get the same problem. Looking at the overall code, there is nothing particular done with the contents for `vowel_substrings`, so just `vowel/consonant_guy_score += 1` would suffice? I think we need to see the original problem formulation, as I don't think this solves the actual problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've just added a paragraph for that. I think the score ends up being based on the distance of the vowel from the end of the string, but that, too, can be easily calculated.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I understood the problem is storing too many strings that are not even needed. @sabik